# AWS Elastic beanstalk failed to launch environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am creating a new application (PHP) using Elastic beanstalk wizard. I get the following:

> Failed to launch environment.
>
> Service:Amazon S3, Message:The bucket does not allow ACLs

Then the application fails to be created.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and had to resolve it. Apparently as of April 2023, AWS changed their bucket policies: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html. You must enable bucket ACL's on the S3 bucket before this will work. Steps to do do this.

1. Login to AWS
2. Go to S3
3. Click on your bucket
4. Navigate to "Permissions"
5. Go down to "Object Ownership"
6. Click Edit, and switch to "ACLs enabled"
7. If required, add the required bucket policy
8. It should work or at least give you a different error

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was creating my first Elastic Beanstalk environment. Since AWS no longer creates the `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` EC2 role for us (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/iam-instanceprofile.html), I had to create it manually. Note that the name of the role is case-sensitive.